# Does {!child} block join support nested queries

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a query like the following

`q={!child of="type:userAccount" v="givenName:test*”}`

Intent: Show me all children of the `type:userAccount where userAccount.givenName:test*`

If I run the query multiple times I get a very different `numFound` difference:
 186,560 to 187,412 (+/0 500).

If I run the “normal” query on just the  parents
`q=type:userAccount givenName:test*`

I get a very stable numFound

Reading the docs it’s not documented as supported but neither do I get an error
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers

Am I using nestedQueries correctly?